# Android Room Relation One-to-Many-to-Many

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I am developing an Android app using the Room Library.

The app has 3 entities, like task, item and subItem.

One task has one or more items and one item has one or more subItem.

I need to query the task with its children. At the moment I query the task, then query items, then query subItems, but I want to make it more efficient.

I have already read this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation, but I don't know how to code this relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Room is a very neat wrapper for SQLite. I'm sure you already knew that.
I'm assuming here that you are familiar with SQL and join statements.
if not read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp).
The reason I'm saying that is that you can actually write whatever you want in the DAO and get around doing many SQL queries.

In your case, you need to define @Enitity for Task, Item & SubItem.
Then you need to define the relations between them meaning what is the foreign key of the Task in the Item and what is the foreign key of the Item in the SubItem.

Example:
**I wrote this from memory without compiling so I might have a few mistakes but it should work.**

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity;
import android.arch.persistence.room.ForeignKey;
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey;

import static android.arch.persistence.room.ForeignKey.CASCADE;

@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Task.class,
                                  parentColumns = "id",
                                  childColumns = "taskId",
                                  onDelete = CASCADE))
public class Item {
    @PrimaryKey public final int id;
    public final int taskId;

    public Item(final int id, final int userId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

You can do the same for subItem.
Now for the DAO.

```
public interface DAO {

    @Query("SELECT * from " + 
        "(LEFT JOIN item ON task.id = item.taskId) " +
        "LEFT JOIN sub_item ON item.id = sub_item.itemId " + 
        "WHERE task.id=:id")
    List getTask(int id);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already do anything like this, but what really want is a method in my DAO like this: @Query("SELECT ...")
List getTaskWithItensWithSubItens(int id);

TaskWithItensWithSubItens{
Task task;
List<ItemWithTask> itens;
}

ItemWithTask{
Item item;
List<SubItem> subItem;
}

Comment: I updated the query to give you a 3 way left join. This should do the trick.